after upgrade magnento 2 version 2.3.4 to 2.4.6-p6

recently i was upgrade magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6-p6 for upgrade
i fired below cmd
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p5 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
after install latest version when i run setup:upgrade it will throw error
There is an error in /chroot/home/a77eba9d/28a6e11fee.nxcli.io/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php at line: 50 Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\StoreThemesResolverInterface#0 /chroot/home/a77eba9d/28a6e11fee.nxcli.io/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Theme\M...') #1 /chroot/home/a77eba9d/28a6e11fee.nxcli.io/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Config/Customization.php(75): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Theme\M...') #2 /chroot/home/a77eba9d/28a6e11fee.nxcli.io/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Theme\Model\Config\Customization->__construct(Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), Object(Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design\Proxy), Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\ThemeProvider), NULL)
i went to upgrade my magento version 2.4.3-p2 to 2.4.6-p5

After big code changes, such as application upgrade, try deleting the content of /generated and /var/cache folders, and then try again bin/magento set:up


First you have to confirm this things.
A. All your third party extensions compatible with magento 2.4.6-p6
B. Your Theme is compatible with magento 2.4.6-p6

Try to disable those extension and change theme to magento default luma for cross verification.

Run the following commands from CLI.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/




@Bhagyesh Bhalodiya
Hey,
Please flush the redis cache
and then execute commands, it will work.
Thank You!

If you are using Redis, flush the Redis cache by using the command redis-cli flushall
If the issue persists, remove the cache directories:
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*


Thank you for your ans. but I don't use Redis. I've tried deleting the 'var/' and 'generated/' directories using 'rm -rf'.

Did you run bin/magento setup:upgrade after that? Does the issue persist?

After running the setup:upgrade command, it isn't functioning properly.

Can you please provide more information about this? Does the original issue persist? Or have you encountered a new issue?
